# Problem while moving Mysql DB from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

I was planning to move mysql DB from windows to Ubuntu. Whenever I try to change lower_case_table_names to 1 (for case insensitivity) using set query it says it is read-only variable.

When I tried updating the my.cnf file and restarted the service it showed no errors but the new config is not loaded.

```
Destination
OS :Ubuntu 12.04
Mysql : 5.5.22
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you converted your existing database table names to lowercase before restarting MySQL? The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) on MySQL website has instructions.

Comment: I haven't even copied the database on to this server. However, after the restart of the service, the new config should have loaded, right? Unfortunately, when we check the variable, the value is still 0. What can be the cause?

Comment: If you're still on Windows I don't you think you can even change the variable to 1. Windows file system isn't case sensitive, don't bother with it until you move the file to the Linux server.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have moved the file to ubuntu. The problem starts now. Whenever I change the lowercase variable to 1. It shows that its read only. When I added the entry in  the config file and restarted mysql service, it still shows that the variable value is 0. I hope you understood my problem. I am not able to change this lower_case_table_names to 1 in ubuntu. Please help.